# Mysql query, custom order

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have the following mysql query:

```
SELECT 
       col1, 
       col2, 
       col3 
FROM 
       guests 
WHERE 
       active = 1 AND 
       guestId IN (233, 255, 254, 226, 182, 231, 113, 121)
```

When I get the results however, I get them ordered by guestId (which is indexed) in ascending order (starting with 121 and ending with 255). I need to show the results on my website in that specific order. Is there a way I can bypass the default order?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the custom order in your ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM guests 
WHERE active = 1 AND guestId IN (233, 255, 254, 226, 182, 231, 113, 121)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(guestId, '233,255,254,226,182,231,113,121');
```

The builtin `FIND_IN_SET()` function returns an integer which is the position that the first argument finds its match in the list. Note the list is a single string argument containin a comma-separated list, whereas your `IN()` predicate needs a variable number of arguments. Also IIRC there must be no spaces in the list you give to FIND_IN_SET().

Answer (score 0):

Append `ORDER BY guestId DESC` to the query so it looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    col1, 
    col2, 
    col3 
FROM 
    guests 
WHERE 
    active = 1 AND 
    guestId IN (233, 255, 254, 226, 182, 231, 113, 121) 
ORDER BY 
    guestId DESC
```